# How to select a node with namespace from XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

IDE: VS 2010, winforms,

I have a xml string

```
string  xmlstr = "<string xmlns="http://example.com/proj1">True|Success</string>";
```

I am trying to select the `<string>` node to get its `InnerText` for subsequent parsing:

```
True|Success
```

using below code:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlstr);          
string message = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("string").InnerText;  //Here getting null Execption error.
```

can you tell me how to select this message from xml?

Comment: Your XPath should be `//string`

Comment: This question is so frequently asked that it becomes difficult to choose from the many available duplicates.

Comment: @Tomalak I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.

Comment: @t3chb0t But it is. As soon as the OP tries to use `//string` and finds out that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `XmlNamespaceManager` to be able to select the node:

[XmlNode.SelectSingleNode Method (String, XmlNamespaceManager)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string xmlstr = "<string xmlns=\"http://example.com/proj1\">True|Success</string>";    
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlstr);

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ab", "http://example.com/proj1");

XmlNode stringNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//ab:string", nsmgr);
string message = stringNode.InnerText;
```

Besides your xml string is invalid in the example because it contains double  quotes inside that are not escaped.

Comment: @Tomalak I've fixed the example. It wouldn't work (and it didn't) anyway with the suggested `XPath` because the node contains a namespace and a `XmlNamespaceManager` was necessary.

Comment: ...an now it exactly matches the duplicate I've linked to. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak oh, sorry, I didn't mean to copy it. I actaully didn't realize that a namespace was used in the other question ;-] and solved it by myself... now I'm pround of me ;-] and I will feel ashamed that I missed this information in the duplicate hehe.

Comment: Prefect explanation, thanks @t3chb0t